# Support of AJAX incapable browsers

Tags: ajax, scala, lift

I want to build a website with rich usage of AJAX however I need to support Javascript/AJAX incapable browsers as well. Is there an method to accomplish this comfortably in Lift framework?

Assume the following scenario - There is a filter snippet and the result-view snippet on a single page. Users that support AJAX will simply send the JSON serialized form which will trigger the server-side handler, set the appropriate ValueCell (I hope it is possible to use Wiring even for this more advanced case) which will invalidate the list view and makes it re-render. However if the user doesn't support AJAX, the form would be sent in the "regular" way making the page fully reload.

This should be generally quite easy to implement (binding the on-submit and in case the Javascript is disabled the form will be sent as it is).

The `Form.ajax` snippet sets the action for the form to `javascript://` so that no posting happens in the case when the Javascript support is not present.

Thank you!

Comment: technically speaking, any browser which is ajax-impaired is not one you should be worrying about. either it's a security-paranoid user with JS disabled, or such an old browser you'll have far bigger problems supporting it beyond the lack of ajax.

Comment: I know. However it's much like a requirement for this project so I would be happy if I would have no-JS fallbacks wherever it is possible.

Comment: btw, what about security-paranoids? One shouldn't keep them in mind at all?

Comment: There is a discussion on this topic here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/liftweb/ZskQ7PhYWcc

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! That pretty much solves my problem.